# How can I renew \includegraphics to always use \shadowbox?

Tags: graphics, shadows

I want to enclose all `\includegraphics` into `\shadowbox`. Therefore I thought to re-define `\includegraphics`:

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}{\shadowbox\includegraphics}
```

so that each time `\includegraphics` is called, actually the graphic is enclosed in a `\shadowbox`. But the above does not work:

> Missing { inserted. 
>                      \do@VerbBox l.80 \includegraphics
>                     {0_home_rkrug_Documents_Publications_2012_handbook_Mana... A left
>   brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in. You might want to delete
>   and/or insert some corrections so that I will find a matching right
>   brace soon. (If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

Any suggestions how I can redefine `\includegraphics` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you're using `\shadowbox` from the `fancybox` package. You need to save the definition of `\includegraphics` and to pass it to `\shadowbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancybox,letltxmacro}

% save the meaning of \includegraphics
\LetLtxMacro\latexincludegraphics\includegraphics

% pass the image to \shadowbox
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \shadowbox{\latexincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{try}
\end{document}
```

In this particular case `\LetLtxMacro` is not really needed and the primitive `\let` would have sufficed, but this approach is safer whenever commands with optional arguments are redefined.

Note that you lose the possibility of using the *-form, use the `clip` option instead.