# Is it possible to fix the width of the included image with `includegraphics`?

Tags: beamer, macros, graphics

I have tried to use the `renewcommand` do redefine includegraphics, as shown [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70556):

```
% save the meaning of \includegraphics
\LetLtxMacro\latexincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{#2}}
```

And for this minimal test case:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% save the meaning of \includegraphics
\LetLtxMacro\latexincludegraphics\includegraphics

\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics{test.png} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

That includes this figure:

[image]

I get this error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.12 \end{frame}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
```

How can I use `renewcommand` on `includegraphics` to fix the figure width?

Comment: You are using it recursivly. Try (untested): `\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\latexincludegraphics[width=5cm]{#2}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's better to set the key globally using `\setkeys`:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.25\textwidth}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also use `\newcommand`, instead of `\renewcommand`. In fact, I would even suggest you doing it in first place, since that way the original `\includegraphics` command is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I define several figure macros for commonly used image sizes (full page, full line, half page, etc.).

You could customize this further by creating custom lengths like `\newlength{\TallFigureHeight} \setlength{\TallFigureHeight}{\textheight}` and then use that as the argument in these commands.

```
\newcommand{\insertWideFigure}[1]{%
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\insertTallFigure}[1]{%
   \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{#1}%
}
```

Usage:

`\insertWideFigure{images/picture}`

Comment: why the downvote?